# How to calculate the beam angle with only X-Z and Y-Z angle information.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

I am going to make a solenoid magnet simulation with a beam source. So, in order to define the beam direction, there are different parameters such as $x$, $x'$ (or $a$ or $P_x/P_0$), $y$, $y'$ (or $b$ or $P_x/P_0$) also known as *4D phase space*.

$a$ parameter defines the angle between $Z$ (beam) axis and $X$-axis, $b$ defines the angle between $Z$ (beam) axis and $Y$-axis

I started with easy way and I defined one constant $b$ value (in rad). As a further step, I wanted to emit the particles as a cone shape by keeping this angle (*$\varphi$ angle in the image below*).

I do not know how can describe this angle by using only $a$ and $b$ angles.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKDGM.png)

Comment: And we don't either, because the only thing labelled in that image where the label matches anything mentioned in your post is $\phi$. You've tossed a lot verbiage around that is basically meaningless without context, and have not supplied that context. Define your terms, and then maybe someone can help you.

Comment: There are two solutions to beam direction - intersection of two cones.